# 2 cities called Caesarea?

Tags: church-history, geography

This may be in the wrong forum but I’ll try. I google searched this at length yesterday but my search terms must be lacking something as the mystery got worse not better. We’re there more than one city or town in late 2nd Temple period called Caesarea? Caesarea, Caesarea-Philippi, Caesarea Maritimia? The geography is confusing as well as the names/descriptions.

I know we have well credentialed experts here somewhere so while you’re chuckling at the dumb question pls help me

Comment: Lots more than two (if you're looking further away than just Palestine): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesarea_(disambiguation)

Answer (score 2):

Yes these are two different cities:

[Caesarea Philippi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesarea_Philippi), literally "Philip's Caesarea"; Ancient Greek: Καισαρεία Φιλίππεια Kaisareía Philíppeia) was an ancient Roman city located at the southwestern base of Mount Hermon.

[image]

[Caesarea Maritima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesarea_Maritima), Greek: Παράλιος Καισάρεια Parálios Kaisáreia), formerly Strato's Tower, also known as Caesarea Palestinae, was an ancient city in the Sharon Plain on the coast of the Mediterranean, now in ruins and included in an Israeli national park

[image]

Comment: Teamwork for the win!  8^D

Comment: Are there explicit unmistakable references to the latter in the New Testament or Old?

Comment: There are no OT references since the city was founded around 20 BCE. As for NT, there are no direct references to the city, but there are some to the region (Sidon) of which the city was the capital: Matthew 15:21; Mark 7:24, and Acts 27:3-4

Comment: Acts 8:40 according to some commentators (link below) refers to the coastal Caesarea “Sebaste”, aka “Maritima”, as the Caesarea that Phillip returns to, not Caesarea Philippi. The context and apparent route of places he passed through support that. See https://biblehub.com/commentaries/acts/8-40.htm